# Separating logic from GUI in java

Tags: java, user-interface, logic

I'm having really hard time splitting up my class into two classes, right now I have the GUI and the logic all together in one class and I want it to be separate, I had a read on objects and classes but I still don't understand how I would split it up for my example, my only "logic" in this program is 3 inner classes which determine what the buttons do (Delete record, save record etc...)

Heres my code, can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String phone;
    private String address;
    private String postcode;
    private String email;
    static String summary;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JPanel buttonspanel;
    private JPanel labelspanel;
    private JPanel tablepanel;
    private JFrame frame;
    private JLabel lblName;
    private JLabel lblEmail;
    private JLabel lblPostcode;
    private JLabel lblAddress;
    private JLabel lblSurname;
    private JLabel lblPhone;
    private JTextField txtName;
    private JTextField txtSurname;
    private JTextField txtPostcode;
    private JTextField txtEmail;
    private JTextField txtPhone;
    private JTextField txtAddress;
    private JButton btnSave;
    private JButton btnUpload;
    private JButton btnDelete;


    String columns[] = {"Name","Surname","Phone","Address","Postcode","Email"};



    private DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
    JTable table = new JTable(model);       



    public AddressBook() {
        createForm();
        createLabels();
        createTextField();
        createButton();
        createTable();
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
    public void createLabels(){
        lblName = new JLabel ("Name");
        lblName.setBounds(10, 30, 100, 20);
        labelspanel.add (lblName);

        lblSurname = new JLabel ("Surname");
        lblSurname.setBounds(10, 50, 100, 20);
        labelspanel.add (lblSurname);

        lblAddress = new JLabel ("Address");
        lblAddress.setBounds(10, 70, 100, 20);
        labelspanel.add (lblAddress);

        lblPhone = new JLabel ("Phone");
        lblPhone.setBounds(10, 90, 100, 20);
        labelspanel.add (lblPhone);

        lblPostcode = new JLabel ("Postcode");
        lblPostcode.setBounds(10, 110, 100, 20);
        labelspanel.add (lblPostcode);

        lblEmail = new JLabel ("Email");
        lblEmail.setBounds(10, 130, 100, 20);
        labelspanel.add (lblEmail);

    }

    public void createTextField(){

        txtName = new JTextField (null);
        txtName.setBounds(110, 30, 150, 20);
        labelspanel.add (txtName);

        txtSurname = new JTextField (null);
        txtSurname.setBounds(110, 50, 150, 20);
        labelspanel.add (txtSurname);

        txtAddress = new JTextField (null);
        txtAddress.setBounds(110, 70, 150, 20);
        labelspanel.add (txtAddress);

        txtPhone = new JTextField (null);
        txtPhone.setBounds(110, 90, 150, 20);
        labelspanel.add (txtPhone);

        txtPostcode = new JTextField (null);
        txtPostcode.setBounds(110, 110, 150, 20);
        labelspanel.add (txtPostcode);

        txtEmail = new JTextField (null);
        txtEmail.setBounds(110, 130, 150, 20);
        labelspanel.add (txtEmail);

    }

    public void createForm(){

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Address Book"); 
        frame.setSize(800,800);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        panel = new JPanel();
        buttonspanel = new JPanel();
        buttonspanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        buttonspanel.setBorder (BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder ());
        labelspanel = new JPanel();
        labelspanel.setBorder (BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder ());
        labelspanel.setLayout(null);
        labelspanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (400,200));
        tablepanel = new JPanel();
        tablepanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(buttonspanel);
        panel.add(labelspanel);
        panel.add(tablepanel);

    }

    public void createButton(){
        btnSave = new JButton ("Save to a file");
        btnSave.addActionListener(new SaveHandler());  
        buttonspanel.add (btnSave);


        btnDelete = new JButton ("Delete from the table");
        btnDelete.addActionListener(new DeleteHandler());  
        buttonspanel.add (btnDelete);

        btnUpload = new JButton ("Add details to table");
        btnUpload.addActionListener(new AddHandler());  
        buttonspanel.add (btnUpload);



    }

    public void createTable(){
        model.setColumnIdentifiers(columns);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        tablepanel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    class SaveHandler implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(e.getSource()==btnSave)
            {
                name = ("");
                surname = ("");
                phone = ("");
                address = ("");
                postcode = ("");
                email = ("");

                name = txtName.getText();
                surname = txtSurname.getText();
                phone = txtPhone.getText();
                address = txtAddress.getText();
                postcode = txtPostcode.getText();
                email = txtEmail.getText();

                summary = ("Name:" +name)+("Surname:" +surname)+("Phone:" + phone)+("Address:" + address)+("Postcode:" + postcode)+("Email:" + email);
                String saveFile = summary;

                try {
                    BufferedWriter reader = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("userinfo.txt"), true));
                    reader.write(saveFile);
                    reader.newLine();
                    reader.close();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "The details were sucessfuly saved");

                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Something went wrong, please try again");
                }
            }
        }

    }


    class AddHandler implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(e.getSource()==btnUpload)
            {

                String nameRow = txtName.getText();
                String surnameRow = txtSurname.getText();
                String phoneRow = txtPhone.getText();
                String addressRow = txtAddress.getText();
                String postcodeRow = txtPostcode.getText();
                String emailRow = txtEmail.getText();
                Object[] row = {nameRow,surnameRow,phoneRow,addressRow,postcodeRow,emailRow};
                model.addRow(row);

            }

        }
    }

    class DeleteHandler implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(e.getSource()==btnDelete)
            {
                int i = table.getSelectedRow();
                if(i >= 0){
                    model.removeRow(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new AddressBook();

    }
```

Comment: "I want it to be separate" - Why do YOU want a separation? If you understood why you want a separation you probably would be able to split easily.

Answer (score 0):

```
    class GUI{      


     Jbutton btnsave;
     Jbutton Delete;
     jbutton update

     HandleAll btnHandler = new  HandleAll(); 

     btnSave.addActionListener(btnHandler);  
     Deletea.ddActionListener(btnHandler);
     update.addActionListener(btnHandler);


      class HandleAll implements ActionListener {

       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       if(e.getSource()==btnSave){
       //on click save button
       }else if(e.getSource()==Delete){
       //on click delete button
       }else if(e.getSource()==update){
      //on click update button
       }

       }
     }


}
```

you can follow above approach to seperate logic from Gui . by the way i have made the HandleAll class a `inner class`. HandleAll implements actionListner interface . on every button press `actionperformed` on this class will get call but by selecting `e.getsource` you can check which button was pressed exactly.try this approach

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make sense, but I need to have two separate .JAVA files for this, one to handle the GUI and one to handle the logic. My issue is I don't know how to have listeners for buttons that don't exist in the same class.

Comment: it is the same concept .there should be referrence to the buttons  from the other class then you can do this.